# Adding Column Constraint in Alter table command in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraints, addition, ddl, alter

I want to add a column constraint with a constraint_name

```
ALTER TABLE Appointments ALTER COLUMN  Hidden SET DEFAULT cast(0 as boolean)
```

This is working. Here no constraint name given. But, I have to add a column constraint name here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your query does not involve any constrains. Instead, you added a default value for a column.

Comment: Default value for a column is a constraint right ? .

Comment: I want to execute like the following . But it wont accept in PostgreSql,

Comment: ALTER TABLE Appointments Add CONSTRAINT DF_Apppointments_Hidden_constraint ALTER COLUMN  Hidden SET DEFAULT cast(0 as boolean)

Comment: no, it is not a constraint. [Constraints are these in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html). `DEFAULT` does not *constrain* a column in any way.

Comment: A default value is not a constraint (it's a _default_ as the name implies). You can't give it a name.

Comment: Also `cast(0 as boolean)` is senseless. Just use `set default false`

Comment: Yes you are correct .Thanks for the help